# Problem refreshing images with same local route path

Tags: css, angular, html, image, typescript

I have an HTML5 img element which loads a local .png file with "src" property, as below:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Temp/example.png"/>
```

Once the image is loaded, "example.png" changes its content to a different image, but the image is still with the same route "file:///C:/Temp/example.png".

The problem is that the image is not refreshed and shows the first image loaded...

If I store the path in public property and apply data binding doesn't work properly. I figure out that it's a problem with browser cache, but I'm not sure at all. Is there any way to refresh the new image?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hi, Alberto, did you try to use some additional random url parts added to main url? like `somepart.png?r=Math.random()` ?

Comment: What do you mean?, maybe with a different ".png" filename?

Comment: You can see solution in link by Mezo. It's fully explain what I mean.